# Interrupting a thread prior to calling Future.get()

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, future

I'm trying to write an integration test that causes an `InterruptedException` to be raised from the production code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    productionObject = new ProductionObject(
            com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    assertThat(productionObject.execute(), equalTo(defaultResponse));
}
```

Inside `productionObject`'s implementation:

```
try {
    for (Future<T> future : executorService.invokeAll(tasks))) {
        results.add(future.get());
    }
    return results;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // preserve interrupt flag
    return defaultResponse;
}
```

Inside `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly()` I see:

```
  if (Thread.interrupted())
        throw new InterruptedException();
```

So I would expect this test to pass consistently.

I've seen this fail in our build server (`results` are returned rather than `defaultResponse`).  I've been unable to reproduce the failure locally, running the test in a while (true) loop, and simulating higher load by running glxgears with software rendering ;-)  Can anyone spot my mistake, give me some suggestions on where to look, or suggest tools that could help me?

Comment: Is the build server using a different JVM? Maybe its executorService works differently.

Comment: @hertzsprung Is there any case in which `results.isEmpty()` returns true in your build servers?

Comment: I tried reproducing the problem, with no success. Did you provide all the relevant code of ProductionObject? I'm asking because maybe somewhere in the code the interrupted flag is being reset. This may happen by an innocent call to Thread.interrupted(), or by handling InterruptedException without setting the flag again. Have you tried debugging to find the place where the flag becomes false?

Comment: @EyalSchneider I can try and reduce this to a real test case tomorrow, but I've been unable to reproduce the problem locally, let alone debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "fixed" this by interrupting the thread from within the `Callable` rather than from the test method itself.  This makes the interruption occur closer to call to `acquireSharedInterruptibly()`.

I can only imagine that somewhere on the code path the interrupt flag is sometimes being cleared (perhaps by JUnit or Maven surefire, which are executing test methods in parallel).  I've probably only reduced the likelihood of the race condition, rather than fixing it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Strange.  I read the code the same way you do.  I see:

1. `FutureTask.get()` calls `Sync.get()`.  I assume we are dealing with `FutureTask` here.
2. `Sync.get()` calls `Sync.innerGet()`
3. `Sync.innerGet()` calls `acquireSharedInterruptibly(0)`;
4. Which has the code right off:

   ```
   if (Thread.interrupted())
       throw new InterruptedException();
   ```

I would think that this would always throw.  Maybe there is some sort of race condition so the thread does not yet know that it has been interrupted?  Have you tried to sleep for 100ms after you interrupt the thread?

I just ran the following test on my multi-cpu Mac and it never fails so it does not look like a race condition -- at least with my architecture and JRE version 1.6.0_41.

```
for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    assertTrue(Thread.interrupted());
}
```

Comment: We are dealing with Guava's `ListenableFutureTask`, which extends `FutureTask` (and does not override `Future.get()`).  Surely sleeping wouldn't make any sense if I'm using `SameThreadExecutor`?  Perhaps using `SameThreadExecutor` isn't the best idea since the test isn't reflecting the `ExecutorService` implementation used in production code.

Comment: It would be interesting to add a `assertTrue(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()));` right after your interrupt call @hertzsprung.

Comment: What about invokeAll()? I expect this line to be interrupted even before the future.get() calls. How is this method implemented in this particular ExecutorService?

Comment: I don't think `invokeAll()` will throw `InterruptedException` unless you are using a bounded blocking queue @EyalSchneider.  It won't `wait()` otherwise.

Comment: @EyalSchneider It's implemented by `AbstractListeningExecutorService`, but I can see from the stacktrace that the InterruptException is coming from `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly()` when this test passes locally.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sameThreadExecutor()` in this context might actually be contra-productive since the interrupt might than occur in one of the tasks. Otherwise the code looks fine. Try using kicking off actual other threads and let one of the tasks wait long enough for your interrupt.